# Caching a PHP object in APC

Tags: php, couchbase, apc

I am trying to reuse the same couchbase bucket for multiple page invocations. What I am doing is storing a bucket in APC like so:

```
$myCluster = new CouchbaseCluster(COUCHBASE_ADDRESS);
$myBucket = $myCluster->openBucket(COUCHBASE_BUCKET);

apc_add('conn', ($myCluser));
apc_add('bucket', ($myBucket));
```

I then fetch the bucket and connection:

```
$test_con = (apc_fetch('conn'));
$test_buck = (apc_fetch('bucket'));
```

Now that i have the bucket instance, i should be able to do this:

```
$res=$test_buck->upsert("cache_test1",  '{"attr": "ran"}');
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Could you describe what happens when it doesn't work?  Also, from a testing perspective, it might be useful to set the envvar LCB_LOGLEVEL higher: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/sdks/php-2.0/logging.html

Comment: I didn't really know what i was doing back then (haha) of course it didn't work.